# MATLAB: Creating tooltips for multiple line objects in a plot using WindowButtonMotionFcn

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to create tooltips for each line in a treeplot-similar plot in MATLAB. I used code examples to create the following script that shows whether the mouse is over a line object:

```
function test_mouseover2
f=figure(1);
axis([0 1 0 1]);
L=line([0.2500 0.5000], [0.6 0.8], 'Color','red');    
set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',{@mousemove,L,process});
end

function mousemove(src,ev,L,process)
obj = hittest(src);
if obj == L
    disp('Yes');
else
    disp('No');
end
end
```

In my further project I need multiple lines in the plot. The simple example in the following shows that two lines are plotted. However, the result in the command window is always "No":

```
function test_mouseover2
f=figure(1);
axis([0 1 0 1]);
L=line([0.2500 0.5000; 0.125 0.25], [0.6 0.8; 0.2 0.6], 'Color','red');

set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',{@mousemove,L,process});
end

function mousemove(src,ev,L,process)
obj = hittest(src);
if obj == L
    disp('Yes');
else
    disp('No');
end
end
```

Is there another approach to check whether the mouse is over a line object or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `mousemove`, test for `any(obj == L)`. This tests whether any of the elements in `L` match `obj`. Since `obj==L` will at most have one non-zero element, this always evaluates to `false` [as far as `if` is concerned](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html#bt7zco5-1):

> An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if it is possible to get the one element of `L` that matches `obj`?

Comment: @stm `find(obj==L)` will return the matching index (or an empty matrix, if no match)

Comment: Wow, it's so easy... Thanks again for your help!